# svg attribute value changes

Tags: javascript, html, svg

When retrieving svg rect height using

```
document.getElementById("height").height.baseVal.value
```

the returned value is sometimes correct and sometimes 0 (or a very small number when inspected in Firefox). Is there a way to ensure that only the correct value is returned?

Comment: Please provide your html & svg markup.

Comment: Make sure get height after **#height** rendered.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question showing the value being 0 on occasion.

Comment: You need to declare the `height` attribute in order to get a result. If your SVG has only the `viewBox` attribute you will get 0. To get a result without declaring the `height` you need to do this: `var s = window.getComputedStyle(svg, null);// where svg is a variable representing your svg element``

console.log(s.getPropertyValue("height"));